# How do I output the Int size in bits, min, and max in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, int, integer, output

I already have an example with Byte, here it is:

```
8
-128
127
```

I need to do the same with type Integer.

Comment: `Int.MAX_VALUE` and `Int.MIN_VALUE` and the size is 32 bits

Comment: You can find the number of bits with an expression such as `(Math.log(Int.MAX_VALUE.toDouble()) / Math.log(2.0)).roundToInt() + 1`.  (The `roundToInt()` is needed because `Int.MAX_VALUE` is 1 less than a power of two, and you can't just add 1 without it overflowing.  And the `+ 1` is because it's signed.)…

Comment: …However, it's much easier just to use `Int.SIZE_BITS`!

Answer (score 3):

Adding onto the above value you can also print the file size of an Int in Bits by doing..

```
println(Int.SIZE_BITS)
```

Full answer:

```
println(Int.SIZE_BITS)
println(Int.MIN_VALUE)
println(Int.MAX_VALUE)
```